# DNN 7: Display Name Format Setting

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7, dotnetnuke-settings

I have attempted to change the Display Name Format in the User Settings for DNN 7 with the following token:

[FIRSTNAME]

But for some reason DNN isn't displaying it like that anywhere across the site. It's still displaying it like [LASTNAME], [FIRSTNAME].

How do I fix this without manually having to go through thousands of automatically populated records?

Comment: Is the setting being saved? Or if you return to the setting page is it still the old format?

Comment: The setting is being saved. Eg., I input which token I want to display, save it, I navigate through the website (noticing the change hasn't taken place), and then return to the User Settings page, the updated token is still there in the input field for that setting.

Comment: Does it work properly for a New User? I think the template might only apply to new users, not sure.

Comment: Just tested it, and yes, it does work properly for a new user. Is there some way to retroactively apply it? (I just thought it would do that on the fly, I have too many user profiles to spend time on manually rearranging).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your existing users you will likely need to update it manually in the Database.

Not positive, but I believe DisplayName is on the User's Table, so you could update it there for each user using a t-sql statement.